# How to replace last comma with '&' after using pull and referencing object on markdown to get pdf on r?

Tags: r, pdf, dplyr, r-markdown

I am using dplyr::pull() to get all values on a dataframe's column. When i call that object to get the values on the pdf, they are separated by commas, which is great. But i was wondering, is there a way to replace that last comma with the '&' character? Thank you.

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: pdf_document
date: "2023-08-27"
---
```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
library(dplyr)
characters <- starwars |> pull(name)
```

The characters on star wars are `r characters` .
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to use a custom function like so:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: pdf_document
date: "2023-08-27"
---
```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
library(dplyr)
characters <- starwars |> pull(name)
```

```{r}
paste1 <- function(x, sep = ", ", sep_last = " & ") {
  last <- x[length(x)]
  paste(paste(x[-length(x)], collapse = sep), last, sep = sep_last) 
}
```

The characters on star wars are `r paste1(characters)`.
````

[image]

Answer (score 1):

what about:

```
characters <- starwars |> pull(name)

characters <- 
    head(characters, -1) |>
    paste(collapse = ', ') |>
    paste(tail(characters, 1), sep = ' & ')
```

(rest as already there)